# Changing directory to Program Files x86 in Python ssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

I am successfully migrating to "Program Files" in my remote desktop through the following Python script running in my local PC:

```
ssh.connect('135.24.237.167',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'sandforce')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd C:/Program\ Files;ls")
stdout.readlines()
```

What should be the correct path if I want to browse to Program Files  ? I am trying the command below, but stdout.readlines() returns an empty buffer:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd C:/Program\ Files\\<x86\>;ls")
stdout.readlines()
```

Thanks,

Comment: I hope this is not your real address, username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running the cygwin sshd. If so, you should use the funky cywin convention for paths (prefix it with `/cygdrive/<driveletter>` and get rid of the ":").

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd '/cigdrive/C/Program Files';ls")
```

Note that if the path contains spaces, you must escape the space or put it between quotes.